# how does bitcoinjs-lib grab utxo

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

So, Let's say I want to create a transaction by using `bitcoinjs-lib`.

As far as I can see, this library doesn't provide the help so that it can automatically figure out/grab unpent transactions for inputs and create a transaction magically.

My question is: Am I the one who has to know unspent transactions that I want to use for the inputs in advance ?

If the answer is `no`, then can you point me to the `bitcoinjs-lib` file that does this ?

If the answer is `yes`, how do I get unspent transactions ? By looking at my transaction list on blockchain and getting each one of them's txid and vouts seem not reasonable. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to provide the UTXO details when building a transaction in bitcoinjs. One should not have to trust a library to provide blockchain data, the library works like a calculator and processes the data that it is given. It's not unreasonable at all, these details are easy to get from your node or an explorer.